# How to break up a date range in sql by months

Tags: sql, date, range, datediff, dateadd

I have two sql tables. they are for employees at a company. one table has the usual details (id,name,surname) and another table has their leave info (empid *foreign key to id in employee table,datefrom,dateto)

I needed to break down the leave structure so that we can display the dates. in an output, we would have :
DateFrom       DateT
18-01-2013     19-01-2013

now if the employee has taken leave that goes over the month (ie, it goes from the 29 to the 5), I would print the values like so:
DateFrom       DateT
29-01-2013     31-01-2013
01-02-2013     05-02-2013

to print this, I used [breaking up a date range by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269889/breaking-up-a-date-range-by-month)
which helped break it down, thanks for that answer.
but how do I display which employee is getting all that leave? as I said, the tables are linked. I tried using

```
select
    e.Firstname,
    e.Surname,
    e.MobileNum,
    convert(varchar(11),case when DateFrom > MonthStart then DateFrom else MonthStart end) as BeginDate,
    convert(varchar(11),case when DateTo < MonthEnd then DateTo else MonthEnd end) as EndDate

from(
    select l.*,
    (
        dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,l.datefrom)+v.number,0)
    ) as MonthStart,
    DATEADD(day,-1,
        dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,l.datefrom)+v.number+1,0)
    ) as MonthEnd

from EmployeeLeave l, Employees E
     inner join master..spt_values v on v.type='P' 
     and v.number between 0 and DATEDIFF(month,l.datefrom,l.dateto)
) s
```

but I get errors saying, multipart identifier could not be bound. and I can't find a spot to say

```
where l.empid = e.empid
```

so could someone please tell me how to fix this. would like to see the employee that is taking leave off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join EmployeeLeave and Employees here:

```
from EmployeeLeave l inner join Employees E
on l.empid = e.id
 inner join master..spt_values v on v.type='P' 
 and v.number between 0 and DATEDIFF(month,l.datefrom,l.dateto)
```

You select the fields from Employees here:

```
from(
select l.*, e.FirstName, e.Surname, e,MobileNum
(
    dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,l.datefrom)+v.number,0)
) as MonthStart,  etc
```

Then, change this:

```
select e.Firstname, e.Surname, e.MobileNum
```

to this

```
select s.Firstname, s.Surname, s.MobileNum
```

The reason is that you are selecting from a derived table named s, not the actual employees table.